# How to use multiple "not in" in an if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to use multiple `not in` in an `if` statement?

```
for each_id in lst:
    if "Audiobook" not in (driver.find_element_by_id('productDetailsTable').text) & "a-popover-root" not in (driver.page_source):
        titles.append(driver.find_element_by_id('title').text)
```

This above code is not working for me and I have tried multiple but couldn't figure it out,

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: `&` is a bitwise operation and is ALMOST CERTAINLY not what you needed here.

Comment: I guess you want to use `and` instead of `&`?

Comment: You just did. Even though logical  AND is `and`, not `&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the logical "and" (`and`), not the bitwise "and" (`&`):

```
if "Audiobook" not in (driver.find_element_by_id('productDetailsTable').text) and "a-popover-root" not in (driver.page_source):
```

Answer (score 0):

use logical and i.e. and instead &